# something is of adj+noun

Tags: nouns

I cannot realize the structure and the meaning of this sentence that says: something is of something else". For example, it's of great use, or something is of great value.

It would be great if one let me know the structure and the meaning.

Comment: "A man of few words" says little. "A man of many parts" is versatile. "A Woman Of No Importance" is a play. A "pearl of great price" is valuable. "A thing of beauty is a joy forever."

Answer (score -1):

I am of the opinion that this is another way of saying subject + verb + adjective. For instance, one can say "It's important", which the word important is an adj, or one can say "It's of very importance", which is another way to convey your opinion, but with the structure of "s+v+of+adj+noun".

Comment: I have a question. In "I am of the opinion" , What does a preposition phrase(of the opinion) function? is it a modifier? if so, what does PP modify?

Comment: "It's of **very** importance" is not standard. 
"Very" is an adverb, this construction uses an adjective, such as "great".